# sql join two tables and get cumulative count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables,

table 1:

```
id    document
--------------
A3  B2 
A3  B400 
A5  B100 
A5  B500   
A7  B200 
A8  B6 
A8  B2 
A8  C1    
A8  B3
```

table 2:

```
id    name
--------------
A1  Jack 
A2  Martin 
A3  Jack 
A4  Thomas 
A5  Jack 
A6  Thomas 
A7  Thomas 
A8  John 
A9  John 
A10 Kate
```

my filter is the following that should compare the `document` column and filter based on this list:

```
WHERE table1.document IN (B2,B400,B100,B500,B200,B6,B2,B3)
```

the result should be like:

```
name    freq
--------------
Jack    4
Thomas  1
John    3
```

explanations:
First I filter the documents I have in my `WHERE IN` clause. Then I look at the remaining documents' corresponding value of `id` column in **table1**, and 
look that `id` up in the second table, first column, and get the corresponding `name` for that id and put it in my results table.
For example, A3 is repeated twice, and its corresponding `name` is `Jack`, so upto now Jack has the value of 3 in `freq` column, but since the next id in 
my table1 is A5, repeated twice, which happens to have `Jack` as its name also, so then `jack` will have 4 as the frequency.
For the next value in table1, A7 has a corresponding name of `Thomas`, since A7 is repeated once, and no other id whose corresponding name is Thomas
is not in my list of table1, then Thomas will have freq of 1 ( I don't have A4, nor A6 in table1).
And in the final example, I have A8 repeated 4 times in table1, but, since my list in `WHERE IN` doesn't have `C1` included, so that entry will be filtered
and not counted, so I have three A8 left, whose name is `John` and then it gets the value of 3.

**here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70d64e) data.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a simple `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` can give the required results:

```
SELECT t2.name, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.document IN ('B2','B400','B100','B500','B200','B6','B2','B3')
GROUP BY t2.name;
```

Comment: @marcel Hi there, I'll try to get back to you for the rest of the questions as soon as I find some spare time. Your posts are always intriguing.